# What are the default file permissions for the home folder?

Tags: permissions, chmod, home-directory

I have somehow inadvertently altered the file permissions of my home directory. I wish to change them back to the default permissions. However, I can´t seem to find out what the default is.

Currently, I have set them to:

```
drwx------
```

What should they be? Does it change depending on if you have your home folder encrypted?

Comment: 755 by default on unencrypted and 700 for encrypted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mine says

```
root45@Ubuntu:~$ ls -dl
drwxr-xr-x 31 root45 root45 4096 2011-10-31 14:06 .
```

Answer (score 1):

I have always thought it is easier to deal numerically rather than alphabetically. An 'R' equates to 4, an 'W' to 2 and e(X)ecute to 1. The standard permissions in a directory equate to 755, which evaluates to read, write, execute for the owner (4 + 2 + 1), read and execute for the group (4 + 1) and read and execute for other. There are other permissions that might be assigned such as the sticky bit etc, but I won't go into them. To set the permissions you could just use a chmod 755 * in the directory. If there are hidden files, those starting with a period, you could try chmod 755 .*

Alan

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I disagree. It does answer the question even if he beat around the bush to get to the point.

Comment: It addresses what the standard permissions are, but not what they should be, nor whether they should be different depending on whether a user's home directory is encrypted.