# Cannot install themes due to permissions error

Tags: permissions

I have looked up several tutorials online, they all have one thing that I don't have on my screen a menu that brings them through "System > Preferences > Appearance." I also can't find my `.themes` folder, unless I am in GNOME 3 but I am not allowed to add anything to it. It tells me i am not the owner even though I am set up as admin.

Can anyone recommend anything?

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/a/69148/63025

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get and install more themes, icons, and pointers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116/how-do-i-get-and-install-more-themes-icons-and-pointers)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download a Theme
2. Extract the theme
3. Move the Theme folder to home/.themes/ (Make sure the folder structure is correct; inside the theme folder there should be a gtk3.0, metacity,gtk2 and possibly a gnome-shell folders) if you don't have the hidden folder ( .) makes a hidden folder create it, to make it show up press CTRL+H.
4. Select it with Gnome Tweak Tool, Install it if you don't have it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i cant access the .themes folder it tells me i am not the owner when i am set up as admin, do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Who is the owner of your home folder?

Comment: I am, my user is the admin. for some reason it tells me the permissions of my home folder can not be determined. I cant figure out how to change this...even when i go to user accounts there isnt much there for me to change, and like i said i am already the admin

Comment: Right click the folder and check the properties, does it say your user is the owner or does it say root do you have read and write permissions? did you used `sudo nautilus` instead of `gksu nautilus`?

Comment: Also that is another question, please open a new one regarding this issue you have.

Comment: and see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/74408/what-are-the-default-file-permissions-for-the-home-folder

Answer (score 0):

To download and install then visit this [link](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/themes-collection-for-ubuntu-1110-unity.html).

Install Ubuntu-Tweaks  to download or change theme.

To install, type into a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Or install gnome tweak tool to change theme. To install, type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Run "Advanced Settings" from application.